# $F(x) = \int_{ 1 - \sqrt{x} }^{ x^{3} } \frac{ \arctan\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) }{ y } dy$ - find $F'(x_0)$ at $x_0=4$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have been banging my head against a wall with this question for over a day. I think I need to use multi-variable Leibnitz (deriving under the integral sign) but it doesn't seem to work out and I don't know where I'm wrong. It might be single variable - I got a solution with that but am not sure its correct.

The Question:

> Find $F'(x_0)$ at $x_0=4$
> $$\displaystyle F(x) = \int_{ 1 - \sqrt{x} }^{ x^{3} } \frac{ \arctan\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) }{ y } dy$$

I've also been given a Hint: 
If $g(x,y)$ is continuous for $\displaystyle{ G(x) = \int_{u(x)}^{v(x)} g(x,y) \, dy }$, then we know that $$ G(x_0) = \int_{u(x_0)}^{v(x_0)} g(x_0,y) \, dy $$

My current solution:

I think it should be $$\frac{3}{4}\arctan(16) + \frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{4})}{4}$$ but am not sure at all. I need to submit it.

Here's what I've done so far - using the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{d(x)}\int_{ u(x) }^{ v(x) } f(t) \,dt = v'(x)\cdot f(v(x))-u'(x)\cdot f(u(x))$$
we get
$$F'(x) = \frac{\arctan(x^3/x)}{x^3} \cdot 3x^2 - \frac{\arctan(\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{x})}{1-\sqrt{x}}$$ 
$x_0$ =4 , we place it in and get the solution. Is this right? the problem is that it doesn't really utilize the hint :/

Comment: You have to use the chain rule and you have to know how to differentiate a function $g$ like $g(x)=\int_a^xf(x,y)dy$.

Comment: I know - I just am not sure whether to use single variable or multi- variable version, and whether or not my final answer is correct (I will be graded on it's accuracy

Comment: If you write your $F$ as a composition of functions you should know what to use.

Comment: Hint: F is a function of one variable. The FTC and the chain rule tell you what to do.

Comment: goes to polylogarithm $L_2(+/-i x/y)$

Comment: I haven't really studied polylogarithms so that's not the direction I should take,  here's what I did do

Comment: This is what you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: I tried it - didn't work either. I think you're right and it's probably the way to go but I can't figure out what's wrong with my solution using it. (not the one in here ^) - also I don't know WHY single variable integral rule fails here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we know we're supposed to use a two variable liebnitz rule variation since there are two variables in the definition of F(x) - we'll derive with it. 
(the rule is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$\int_{ 1 - \sqrt{x} }^{ x^{3} } \frac{ \arctan\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) }{ y } dy = \int_{ 1 - \sqrt{x} }^{ x^{3} } \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{ \arctan\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) }{ y } d(y) + \frac{ \arctan\left( \frac{x^3}{x} \right) }{ x^3 } * 3x^2 + \frac{ \arctan\left( \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{x} \right) }{ 1-\sqrt{x} }*\left(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)$$
Let's focus on the integral now - we'll first derive it partially with respect to x and then we can integrate for y.  
$$\int_{ 1 - \sqrt{x} }^{ x^{3} } \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{ \arctan\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) }{ y } d(y) = \int_{ 1 - \sqrt{x} }^{ x^{3} } \frac{1}{y} * \frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^2} * \frac{-y}{x^2}d(y)$$

notice we can use the hint now to substitute $x$ for $x_0$ - or 4 in this case,
we can also substitute x for 4 with the other expressions - we get:
$$ \int_{-1 }^{ 64 } \frac{1}{y} * \frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{y}{4} \right)^2} * \frac{-y}{16}d(y) + \frac{ 3arctan(16) }{ 4 } + \frac{ \arctan\left( \frac{-1}{4} \right) }{-1 }*\left(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{4}}\right)$$
And we're essentially done - it's smooth sailing from here.
just remember to integrate correctly.
The final answer should be $\frac{arctan(16)}{2}$ :)